# docker web server exiting without error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I have my project set with docker-compose. Was working fine until today when I rebuilt the web container. Now whenever I want to start it using `docker-compose up` it just exits without an Error message:

```
web_1        | => Booting Unicorn
web_1        | => Rails 3.2.22.5 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
web_1        | => Call with -d to detach
web_1        | => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
web_1        | Exiting
```

If I run it with --verbose, `docker-compose --verbose up`, the following lines show after 'Exiting':

```
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker wait <- (u'a03b58f2116698d670f86155cd68605a148143b83ee3351a5e5a4808d682afc9')
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- (u'a03b58f2116698d670f86155cd68605a148143b83ee3351a5e5a4808d682afc9')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "POST /v1.25/containers/a03b58f2116698d670f86155cd68605a148143b83ee3351a5e5a4808d682afc9/wait HTTP/1.1" 200 30
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker wait -> 1
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/a03b58f2116698d670f86155cd68605a148143b83ee3351a5e5a4808d682afc9/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {u'AppArmorProfile': u'docker-default',
 u'Args': [u'redis:6379',
           u'--',
           u'./wait-for-it.sh',
           u'postgres:5432',
           u'--',
           u'bundle',
           u'exec',
           u'rails',
           u's',
```

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  memcached:
    image: memcached:1.5.2-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "11211:11211"

  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.4-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ~/.myapp-data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=myapp_development
      - POSTGRES_USER=default
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret

  redis:
    image: redis:3.2.0-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ~/.myapp-data/redis:/data
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: "Dockerfile-dev"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    command: ./wait-for-it.sh redis:6379 -- ./wait-for-it.sh postgres:5432 -- bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/apps/myapp
    depends_on:
      - memcached
      - redis
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "80:3000"
    env_file:
      - .env
    extra_hosts:
     - "api.myapp:127.0.0.1"
     - "api.getmyapp:127.0.0.1"
     - "my.app:127.0.0.1"
```

EDIT:

Here are the contents of Dockerfile-dev, required on the comments:

```
FROM ruby:2.3.7-slim

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get -y install software-properties-common libpq-dev build-essential \
    python-dev python-pip wget curl git-core \
    --fix-missing --no-install-recommends --allow-unauthenticated

# Set install path for reference later.
ENV INSTALL_PATH /opt/apps/engine
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH
RUN gem install bundler
WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

ADD Gemfile $INSTALL_PATH
ADD Gemfile.lock $INSTALL_PATH
RUN bundle install

RUN find /tmp -type f -atime +10 -delete

ADD . $INSTALL_PATH
RUN cp config/database.docker-dev.yml config/database.yml

CMD [ "bundle", "exec", "rails", "s", "-p", "3000", "-b" "0.0.0.0" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker containers exit as soon as the commands run inside them are finished. From the logs you have posted, it seems like the container has 'nothing else' to do after starting up the server. You need to run the process in the foreground or have some sort of `sleep` to keep the container alive.

Comment: From the logs it looks like the server is running in the foreground. The container shouldn't exit while the server is still running so I can't see how this would be an issue.

Comment: don't get it @grevetii, rails s should keep the server running and therefore container should be up

Comment: @ntonnelier can you post contents of your Dockerfile "Dockerfile-dev"?

Comment: just added in the question @gravetii